# Javascript - Apply trim function to each string in an array

Tags: javascript, function, trim

Want to trim each string in an array, e.g., given

```
x = [' aa ', ' bb '];
```

output

```
['aa', 'bb']
```

My first trial is

```
x.map(String.prototype.trim.apply)
```

It got "TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on undefined, which is a undefined and not a function" in chromium.

Then I tried

```
x.map(function(s) { return String.prototype.trim.apply(s); });
```

It works. What's the difference?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`String.prototype.trim.apply` is the [`Function.prototype.apply` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) without being bound to `trim`. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will invoke it with the string, the index and the array as arguments and nothing (`undefined`) for the [`this`Arg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) - however, `apply` expects to be called on functions:

```
var apply = String.prototype.trim.apply;
apply.call(undefined, x[0], 0, x) // TypeError
```

What you can do is passing the `trim` function as the context for `call`:

```
[' aa ', ' bb '].map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim)
// ['aa', 'bb']
```

What happens here is

```
var call = Function.prototype.call,
    trim = String.prototype.trim;
call.call(trim, x[0], 0, x) ≡
      trim.call(x[0], 0, x) ≡
            x[0].trim(0, x); // the arguments don't matter to trim
```

Comment: I see. I thought that `fun` would have the same meaning with `function(x) { return fun(x); }`.

Comment: This won't work on IE8: String.prototype.trim doesn't work with IE8.

Comment: @SachinKainth: The question is not about trim, OP assumes that it is available. If you want to try out the snippets in IE8, you obviously will need to shim `trim` and `map`.

Comment: This is very outdated with ES6 syntax you can do this much easier: `const newArray = oldArray.map(string => string.trim())`

Comment: @svelandiag The explanation why `apply` isn't bound, and how to use the `thisArgument`, is still accurate. Of course, `arr.map(function(str) { return str.trim(); })` or `arr.map(str => str.trim())` has always been simpler.

Answer (score 153):

Or this can be solved with arrow functions:

```
trimmed_x = x.map(s => s.trim());
```

Comment: I suggest: `let trimedArr = oldArr.map(str => str.trim());`

Comment: @Dominic I am using this but when I minify my js that time it will give the error
I am using https://javascript-minifier.com/ site for minify js

Comment: @SachinSarola looks like that minifier is out of date with modern JS syntax. It's better to build and minify your JS as part of a build pipeline anyway using e.g. webpack

Comment: For me, `x.map(s => return s.trim());` worked but the above did not.

Comment: @rafagarci that's a syntax error, you'd need braces around the `return` statement

Answer (score 40):

The simple variant without dependencies:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     array[i] = array[i].trim()
 }
```

ES6 variant:

```
const newArray = oldArray.map(string => string.trim())
```

ES6 function variant:

```
const trimmedArray = array => array.map(string => string.trim())
```

Answer (score 28):

If you are using JQuery, then a better way to do this, as it will work with IE8 as well (I need to support IE8) is this:

```
$.map([' aa ', ' bb ', '   cc '], $.trim);
```

Comment: @DenysSéguret "If" is the keyword here.

Answer (score 18):

First, do it simply :

```
x.map(function(s) { return s.trim() });
```

Then, the reason why the first one doesn't work is that the string is passed as argument to the callback, not as context. As you pass no argument to `apply`, you get the same message you would have got with

```
var f = String.prototype.trim.apply; f.call();
```

---

Now, mostly for fun, let's suppose you're not happy with the fact that `map` use the callback this way and you'd want to be able to pass a function using the context, not the argument.

Then you could do this :

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "maprec", {
  value: function(cb){
      return this.map(function(v){ return cb.call(v) })
  }
});
console.log([' aa ', ' bb '].maprec(String.prototype.trim)); // logs ["aa", "bb"]
```

I said "mostly for fun" because modifying objects you don't own (Array's prototype here) is widely seen as a bad practice. But you could also make a utilitarian function taking both the array and the callback as arguments.

Comment: You mean the same message you would have got with `String.prototype.trim.apply.call()`, don't you?

Answer (score 5):

I just compared some ways to trim an array of strings to get the shortest and fastest method. Who is interested in, here is a performance test on jsperf: http://jsperf.com/trim-array-of-strings

```
var chunks = "  .root  ,  .parent  >  .child  ".split(',')
var trimmed1 = chunks.map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim);
var trimmed2 = chunks.map(function (str) { return str.trim(); });
var trimmed3 = chunks.map(str => str.trim());
var trimmed4 = $.map(chunks, $.trim);
```

Note: *jQuery is just here to compare the number of characters to type ;)*

Answer (score 3):

Influencing from Bergi's perfect answer, i just would like to add, for those methods which won't take a `this` argument, you may achieve the same job as follows;

```
var x = [' aa ', ' bb '],
    y = x.map(Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.trim))
```

Comment: Worked really well!

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple and stupid:

#### Code

```js
[' aa ', ' b b ', '   c c '].map(i=>i.trim());
```

#### Output

```
["aa", "b b", "c c"]
```

Comment: Why repeat an answer already given one year earlier?

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = [" aa ", " bb "];
console.log(x); // => [" aa ", " bb "]

// remove whitespaces from both sides of each value in the array
x.forEach(function(value, index){
  x[index] = value.trim();
});

console.log(x); // => ["aa", "bb"]
```

All major browsers support `forEach()`, but note that `IE` supports it only beginning from version 9.

Answer (score 1):

```js
x = [' aa ', ' bb ', 'cccc '].toString().replace(/\s*\,\s*/g, ",").trim().split(",");

console.log(x)
```

Answer (score -2):

**Another ES6 alternative**

```
const row_arr = ['a ', ' b' , ' c ', 'd'];
const trimed_arr = row_arr.map(str => str.trim());
console.log(trimed_arr); // <== ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: array_map is not a native JS function and not defined here. => does not work.

Comment: @Greg the first version of this answer included an unspecified `array_map()` method

Comment: @musemind My mistake -- I should have looked at edits

Answer (score -2):

```
    ### Code
    <!-- language: lang-js -->

     var x=  [' aa ', ' b b ', '   c c ']
var x = x.split(",");
            x = x.map(function (el) {
                return el.trim();
                console.log(x)

    ### Output
    <!-- language: lang-none -->
        ["aa", "b b", "c c"]
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: Are you sure about that? When trying to use your code, the following error is thrown: `TypeError: x.split is not a function`

Comment: ### Try once this code....     var x=  [' aa ', ' b b ', '   c c ']
var x = x.split(",");
            x = x.map(function (el) {
                return el.trim();
                console.log(x)

Comment: ### TRY var x = x.split(",");
            x = x.map(function (el) {
                return el.trim();
                console.log(x)