# Can't use String#trim as a callback for Array#map

Tags: javascript, string, prototype

For some reason I can't use `String.prototype.trim.call` as a callback for array methods, such as `map` or `filter`.

In this case, two functions work the same:

```
function trim(string) {
  return string.trim();
}

var string = ' A ';

trim(string);                       // 'A'
String.prototype.trim.call(string); // 'A'
```

However, when I try to pass them as a callback for an array method, second one fails:

```
var array = [' A', 'B ', ' C '];

array.map(trim);                       // ['A', 'B', 'C'];
array.map(String.prototype.trim.call); // TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ubUHiHon/1/edit?js,console

I assume in a latter case that `this` doesn't point to an array element, but I would like to get clear explanation of what's happening.

Comment: exact duplicate of [Javascript - Apply trim function to each string in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293997/javascript-apply-trim-function-to-each-string-in-an-array) - sorry that I've answered twice now :-)

Comment: @Bergi looks like it is, sorry for that. But, as you can imagine, it's almost impossible to find one (I've honestly spend required 15 minutes). I've tried to make the title as general and accurate as possible.

Comment: Also an elegant solution to this problem would be ES6 arrow function: `array.map(s => s.trim());`.

Comment: Yeah, when encountering the question, I knew it was a duplicate but could not find it. So I wrote an answer only to discover the old one thereafter :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> String.prototype.trim.call(string); // 'A'
> array.map(String.prototype.trim.call); // TypeError: undefined is not a function
> ```

When you invoke the `call` method in the first case, its [`this` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is bound to the `String.prototype.trim` function. In the second case, you just access the `call` function without having it bound to anything - you could just have used

```
array.map(Function.prototype.call)
```

This method is getting invoked with nothing as the `this` value, the element from your array, the index and the whole array as parameters. When you call `call` not on a function, it throws. You can either use the second parameter of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to fix the `this` value for the `call`:

```
array.map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim)
array.map(Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.trim))
```