# Using JavaScript's map with an object's methods

Tags: javascript

If I have an array of Strings that represent numbers, and want to convert the type of every entry in the array to Number, I can use `map`:

```
var stringNumbers = ["11", "23", "5813"];
stringNumbers.map(parseFloat);
// [11, 23, 5813]
```

This works because `parseFloat` is globally accessible. However, if I want the result of an object's methods, I seem to need to use an anonymous function.

```
var Dog = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
};

Dog.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
};

var dogs = [new Dog("Beatrice"), new Dog("Baxter")];

dogs.map(function(dog) {
  return dog.getName();
});
// ["Beatrice", "Baxter"]
```

Ideally, I would be able to do something like:

```
dogs.map(getName); // ["Beatrice", "Baxter"]
```

But this does not work because getName is not globally accessible.

Is there a way to bind each function executed by `map` to the context of the object it is iterating over?

Comment: `dogs.map(Function.prototype.call.bind(Dog.prototype.getName))` - uh. Use the function expression for your own sanity :-)

Comment: It is possible but SUPER UGLY. Youd be better of with just having a standalone getDogName(dog) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It technically **IS** possible as

```
var r = dogs.map(Function.prototype.call.bind(Dog.prototype.getName));
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VCvp7/

Explanation:

```
Function.prototype.call.bind(Dog.prototype.getName)
```

returns a function reference that is equal to `Dog.prototype.getName.call` and that expects the first parameter as a context (the `this` value to use during the call to `getName`), which is what `map()` passes the exact `Dog` instance to.

**PS**: sorry, cannot explain it better. If you don't get it - just spend couple more minutes to figure it out.

Comment: That. Is. Absolutely. Brilliant. I'm not saying I'd *use* it. But...

Comment: Brilliant, maybe. Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/21186656/2180189 ? Certainly. Useful & readable? NOPE. Why not just make a helper function for getting a dog name?

Comment: @MightyPork: OP didn't know if it is even possible. And if it is - OP didn't know if it's readable. So I'm sure OP will finally choose an explicit anonymous function instead. I agree it's a duplicate though.

Comment: What it the function was defined in the Dog constructor? Is there still an option then? http://jsfiddle.net/NAw79/

Comment: I don't think it is. Both use the same underlying mechanism, but I don't think the question duplicates that question.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd: **Excellent** question. I think the answer then is what my now-deleted answer was: Nope, sorry, can't do it. You have to use a function (anonymous or otherwise).

Comment: @Andrew Shepherd: not an option anymore. There is no a shared function to bind to.

Answer (score 1):

If I had the underscore library in my project, I would use invoke:

```
// Use _.invoke to call method getName() on each dog in dogs
var dogNamesInvoke = _.invoke(dogs, 'getName');
// ["Beatrice", "Baxter"]
```

But also realize that there is a second argument you can pass to map that is thisArg.

```
// Use Array.map but pass the function name 'getName' as the 2nd parameter to map
var dogNamesMap = dogs.map(function(value) {
    var functionName = this;
    return value[functionName].apply(value);
}, 'getName');
// ["Beatrice", "Baxter"]
```

Here is a [link to a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N3OeuR?p=info) that shows your original code along with these two other options.