# Passing Object Method as Parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, functional-programming, prototypal-inheritance

I'm writing JavaScript unit tests for Mongo collections. I have an array of collections and I would like to produce an array of the item counts for those collections. Specifically, I'm interested in using `Array.prototype.map`. I would expect something like this to work:

```
const collections = [fooCollection, barCollection, bazCollection];
const counts = collections.map(Mongo.Collection.find).map(Mongo.Collection.Cursor.count);
```

But instead, I get an error telling me that `Mongo.Collection.find` is undefined. I think this might have something to do with `Mongo.Collection` being a constructor rather than an instantiated object, but I would like to understand what's going on a little better. Can someone explain why my approach doesn't work and what I need to change so that I can pass the `find` method to `map`? Thanks!

Comment: So `fooCollection` and such are `Mongo.Collection` instances? And what are you trying to `find` in the first call?

Comment: Perhaps you actually want to use `Mongo.Collection.prototype.find`?

Comment: Aha. I thought that too and tried it, but it still gave me the undefined error. I tried it again and realized that `Mongo.Collection.prototype.find` _does_ work. The problem is that `map` calls `find(arrayItem)` for each element rather than `arrayItem.find()`. I can pass map an anonymous procedure to do what I want. This is probably better anyway because then I can return the count from a single function, rather than calling `map` twice. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`find` and `count` are prototype functions that need to be invoked as methods (with the proper `this` context) on the collection instance. `map` doesn't do that.

The best solution would be to use arrow functions:

```
const counts = collections.map(collection => collection.find()).map(cursor => cursor.count())
```

but there is also [an ugly trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21186656/1048572) that lets you do without:

```
const counts = collections
.map(Function.prototype.call, Mongo.Collection.prototype.find)
.map(Function.prototype.call, Mongo.Collection.Cursor.prototype.count);
```