# Binding a Javascript function to a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to bind one of either `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase` to a variable, and I'm missing some step along the way. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(flag) {
        arr[i] = arr[i].toUpperCase();
    }
    else {
        arr[i] = arr[i].toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

I'm hoping I can do something like:

```
let func = flag  ? String.prototype.toUpperCase : String.prototype.toLowerCase;
arr = arr.map(x=>func(x));
```

While I can set the function, it looks like I'm not using it right, as I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: String.prototype.toLowerCase called on null or undefined`. What am I missing here?

Comment: They're methods. You need to call them *on* `x`, not pass it as an argument.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21186398/1048572) for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Use `.call`for such things (or .apply, whatever).

Comment: FYI, *as* you were ticking the "accept" checkmark, I added to the middle of my answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @T.J.Crowder. I went with your first suggestion. Code already working :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* do it that way, but you have to use [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) (or `.apply`) so you set `this` correctly within the call to `toUpperCase`/`toLowerCase`, since they expect to see the string to use as `this`, not as a passed parameter:

```
let func = flag  ? String.prototype.toUpperCase : String.prototype.toLowerCase;
arr = arr.map(x=>func.call(x));
//-------------------^^^^^
```

*(I also dropped the `let` from in front of `arr` on the second line, as otherwise `arr` on the right-hand side of the `=` would be `undefined`. [Or, depending on where/how `arr` was previously declared, it would be an error.])*

Example:

```js
let arr = ["one", "TWO", "three", "FOUR"];
const flag = Math.random() < 0.5;
console.log("Flag is: " + flag);
let func = flag  ? String.prototype.toUpperCase : String.prototype.toLowerCase;
arr = arr.map(x=>func.call(x));
console.log(arr);
```

Another option is to give yourself a wrapper function, which you can then call the way you wanted to call it:

```
let func = flag ? s => s.toUpperCase() : s => s.toLowerCase();
arr = arr.map(x=>func(x));
```

Example:

```js
let arr = ["one", "TWO", "three", "FOUR"];
const flag = Math.random() < 0.5;
console.log("Flag is: " + flag);
let func = flag ? s => s.toUpperCase() : s => s.toLowerCase();
arr = arr.map(x=>func(x));
console.log(arr);
```

But the easier thing in this specific case is to just use brackets notation and a string function name:

```
let funcName = flag  ? "toUpperCase" : "toLowerCase";
arr = arr.map(x=>x[funcName]());
```

Example:

```js
let arr = ["one", "TWO", "three", "FOUR"];
const flag = Math.random() < 0.5;
console.log("Flag is: " + flag);
let funcName = flag  ? "toUpperCase" : "toLowerCase";
arr = arr.map(x=>x[funcName]());
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`call`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_call.asp) the function using `func.call(x)` - see demo below:

```js
let func = true  ? String.prototype.toUpperCase : String.prototype.toLowerCase;
let arr = ['test', 'TEST', "Test"].map(x=>func.call(x));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks Thanks t I will hav