# .Trim Is Not A Function Error When Trying To Remove The Space From Returned Data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `DataTable` which is being populated by `JSON`. The days of the week (for example) are returning as a `string` which i am applying `.split(',')` to and is working in my `forEach` function, but i need to apply a class to my days returned buttons but due to the space in the string it only falls into my 'Mon' button and not the rest due to the space.

**Working code**

```
var selectedDays = modifyRecordData.selectedDays;
var splitSelectedDays = selectedDays.split(',');
console.log(splitSelectedDays);

splitSelectedDays.forEach(day => {
  if(day == 'Mon') {
    alert('in Mon')
    $('#mon').removeClass('btn-default');
    $('#mon').addClass('btn-primary');
  }

  if (day == 'Tue') {
    alert('in Tue')
    $('#tue').removeClass('btn-default');
    $('#tue').addClass('btn-primary');
  }

  // AND SO ON
})
```

This also returns

[image]

I have tried the following but none are working

```
var selectedDays = modifyRecordData.selectedDays;
var splitSelectedDays = selectedDays.split(',').trim();
```

and

```
var selectedDays = modifyRecordData.selectedDays;
var splitSelectedDays = selectedDays.split(',').trim();
var test = splitSelectedDays.trim();
```

also thruught about trying in the actual `loop` as each one returned as a `string` using the below

```
splitSelectedDays.forEach(day => {
      splitSelectedDays.trim();
```

But always get the function error.

I am wanting to remove the space, then lowercase the value then i can use the `var` in on `addClass` function rather than an `IF` for each day of the week

Comment: You can't `trim()` an array. Only a string. See the duplicate for how to apply trim to all the strings in an array. This answer specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41183617/519413

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`split` in `selectedDays.split(',').trim();` will create an array. There is no `trim` for array. So you can iterate the array and apply trim if it is a string

You can do like this

```
splitSelectedDays.forEach(day => {
  let val = day.trim();
  // rest of the code
})
```

Comment: This looks like a comment.

Comment: @brk Perfect, i was about to go down the road of `.replace` but this is exactly what i was after

Answer (score 2):

`var splitSelectedDays = selectedDays.split(',').trim();`

This is your problematic line.

`selectedDays.split(',')` will return an array of strings. Trim is a method on a string, not an array of strings, that removes leading/trailing whitespace.

You will have to apply `trim()` to each individual element in the array.

For example

```
var splitSelectedDays = selectedDays.split(',');

for (var i=0; i < splitSelectedDays.length; i++)
{
    splitSelectedDays[i] = splitSelectedDays[i].trim();
}
```